# Potree/Three.js - Where can I find the real time camera (active camera) position coordinates?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, point-clouds

I'm developing an app using React, which uses the Potree viewer (https://github.com/potree/potree) to display large points cloud files; within the viewer I'm trying to display the real-time camera coordinates (X, Y, Z) to the user, as well as will use them to optimise the cloud rendering.

I have been able to source where the coordinates are, by getting the active camera (viewer.scene.getActiveCamera()) and finding the coordinates in viewer.scene.cameraP.position.x/y/z.
Though these values seem static, and I'm saying this because I have tried to update my React component using a useEffect() hook, based on the changing of any of the coordinates, which doesn't work.

Is there anyone who encountered the same issue before and could help me out in finding/sourcing the camera coordinates real-time values, or assist me in actually using the values I have already found and make them updating real time in React?

```
function Coordinates({ viewer, drawerOpen }) {
  const myActiveCamera = viewer.scene.getActiveCamera();
  const [cameraCoords, setCameraCoords] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello");
    if (viewer !== null && viewer.scene !== null) {

      setCameraCoords(myActiveCamera.position);
    }
  }, [myActiveCamera.position.x, myActiveCamera.position.y, myActiveCamera.position.z]);

  console.log(viewer);
  console.log(myActiveCamera);
  console.log(cameraCoords);

  return (
    <Container maxWidth={false} style={{ marginLeft: drawerOpen && '210px' }}>
      <Contents container alignItems="center">
        <CameraAlt /> {/*Camera Icon*/}

        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />

        {viewer ? (
          <Typography variant="p">
            X: {cameraCoords.x.toFixed(8)}
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="p">X: 0.0</Typography>
        )}

        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />

        {viewer ? (
          <Typography variant="p">
            Y: {cameraCoords.y.toFixed(8)}
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="p">Y: 0.0</Typography>
        )}

        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />

        {viewer ? (
          <Typography variant="p">
            Z: {cameraCoords.z.toFixed(8)}
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="p">Z: 0.0</Typography>
        )}
      </Contents>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours spent investigating and trying, I have come up with a solution.
The principle behind it is the same as a digital clock.

Here's the code:

```
function Coordinates({ viewer, drawerOpen }) {

  //Declaring the state for the cameraposition coordinates and setting their default to 0
  const [activeCameraCoordinates, setActiveCameraCoordinates] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 });

  //The useEffect and the timer, work together to achieve a real time value update displayed to the user
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (viewer !== 'undefined' && viewer !== undefined && viewer !== null) {
        let cameraPosition = viewer.scene.getActiveCamera().position;
        setActiveCameraCoordinates(cameraPosition);
      }
    }, 100)
  })

  return (
    <Container maxWidth={false} style={{ marginLeft: drawerOpen && '210px' }}>
      <Contents container alignItems="center">
        <CameraAlt />

        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />
        <Typography variant="p">X:
          {activeCameraCoordinates.x.toFixed(2)}
        </Typography>
        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />
        <Typography variant="p">Y:
          {activeCameraCoordinates.y.toFixed(2)}
        </Typography>
        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />
        <Typography variant="p">Z:
          {activeCameraCoordinates.z.toFixed(2)}
        </Typography>
      </Contents>
    </Container >
  );
}
```